# Current date in Oracle Db

Tags: sql, oracle, date

```
Date        Bus value
2014-02-05  1   10
2014-02-06  1   15
2014-02-07  1   16
2014-02-08  2   20
2014-02-09  2   17
2014-02-10  2   19
```

I have the above records already entered in a table in my database, say yesterday. I want to show the record based on `sysdate`. e.g. if today is 2014-02-05 show:

```
Date        Bus value
2014-02-05  1   10
```

Then, tomorrow show:

```
2014-02-06  1   15
```

Comment: You already know about `sysdate`, so what problem are you having?

Comment: -1 Are you asking people to write the code for you? This is not a valid SO question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT "DATE", BUS, VALUE
FROM {your_table}
WHERE "DATE" >= trunc(sysdate) and "DATE" < trunc(sysdate+1)
```

Comment: the sysdate bit goes in the WHERE clause not the select list.